# MySQL timeout/crashing sending much data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to send 562 rows of data from a XLS document using http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs

Every single row is a user that needs to be saved, but when this is running around 180-200 rows Laravel crashes.

Can this be Laravel, my XAMPP server (where I'm running the script) or the database itself?

```
        $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();


    Excel::load($path, function($reader) {

        $data = $reader->get();

        foreach($data as $row) {

            $rows = User::where('email', $row['e_postadress'])->count();

            if($rows == 0)
            {
                if($row['status'] == "Administrat&ouml;r")
                {
                    $admin = 1;
                }
                else 
                {
                    $admin = 0;
                }

                $user = new User;

                $user->email = $row['e_postadress'];
                $user->fname = $row['fornamn'];
                $user->lname = $row['efternamn'];

                $user->save();
            }

        }

    }, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Can we see the code you have to do this? How does a crash manifest itself? Do you get an error?

Comment: Perhaps its exceeding the PHP max execution time ?

Comment: Yes, it could be a timeout problem, but also a memory or overflow problem. It all depends on the errors you see.

Comment: I guess you try to do it bad way (one massive query) instead of the better way (loop over file with many single queries). But I can only guess that much from the code you provided.

Comment: Edited the post and added the code, the crash im getting it just "woops, something went wrong" nothing the laravel logs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) I have fix this problem with the MySQL command : LOAD DATA INFILE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

You can add big file in few seconds. But I think you must transform your .xls in .csv

Example (codeIgniter syntax, please adapt for laravel):

```
        $dataload = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Path_of_the_file" 
                    REPLACE
                    INTO TABLE gc_csv CHARACTER SET "latin1"
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
                    IGNORE 1 LINES
                ';

    return (bool)$this->db->query($dataload);
```

Comment: OP wants to do it through php

Comment: Yes, and ? He can use SQL with php ...
I have update my message for explain with code